# Android Multi-Step Wizard Examples

Tags: gui-design, android, wizard

I am designing a multi-step wizard to display at the startup of my Android App. Looking for examples which serves as both tutorial and tour of the major benefits of the app. So far I haven't found many examples yet. Please share if you know of any great UX designs in this category.

Comment: Any example of a wizard in an app, phone or tablet, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are some brilliant examples of start-up walkthroughs. Typically there are two types of start-up prompts, **walkthroughs** and **coach screens**.

### Walkthroughs

These are usually slides, often with animations that contain an overview of features, ending in a call-to-action. 
**Twine**: One good example of animations is Twine, which makes you scroll through to the final. An indicator of state is shown at the bottom.

[image: Twine's walkthrough screens]

**Cal**: has a single screen with a video playing in the background. Might not explain features but sets the mood for the app.
[image: Cal's video walkthrough]

### Coach Screens

These are overlays over the actual UI that show up the first time the user opens the app.

**Kitkat**: Android 4.4's coach screens.
[image: Kitkat's coach screens]

You could find more examples [here.](http://www.android-app-patterns.com/category/tutorials)

Answer (score 2):

The best example I've seen of this lately is to have a dark layer on top of your app with hand written notes and arrows.

I think this is a better way to do a Wizard because it lets you see the app while it explains things but still makes it clear that you're not really *in* the app yet.

This is a rough draft I was working on, but it demonstrates the idea.

[image]

Comment: The blinkbox app for android (UK VOD service) https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blinkbox.tablet.live&hl=en_GB
has a nice version of this approach on first load. Worth a look if you can access it in your region.